# Images not being cached between navigations

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I've got a project im working on https://github.com/Bijig0/liner_rn When I click on a 'Queue' button and it navigates to a details page, I want the image to be cached from the list page to the details page.

i.e
Currently it is like this https://youtube.com/shorts/L3hTAuyqxRM

I want it to be like this https://youtube.com/shorts/DCkFUixvAoU
(Associated Snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@meg_hidey/4b5ac4?platform=ios)

I'm not sure what is causing the issue in my actual project for images to not load like they are in the snack if someone could help point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use react-native-fast-image, it is a performant React Native component for loading images. FastImage aggressively caches all loaded images.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fast-image

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't use react-native-fast-image in the Snack and it still cached the images tho, it just doesn't in my actual project which is what im confused by. I'd prefer to not use rnfi and figure out how to use the native Image component if possible